# Android alertdialog adjust custom view to matchparent

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to create an AlertDialog with an EditText which height matches the whole dialog window. is it possible to do that without create a custom layout?

what im trying is:

```
final EditText inputImports = new EditText(getContext());
                    inputImports.setMaxLines(500);
                    inputImports.setInputType(TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);

                    AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getContext()).setTitle(R.string.importar).setMessage(R.string.importCustomList).setView(inputImports).setCancelable(false).setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null).create();
                    alert.setOnShowListener(dialog12 -> {
                        ((AlertDialog) dialog12).getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                        inputImports.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                        inputImports.requestLayout()
                    });
                    alert.show();
```

this makes the dialog window matches the phone height but the edittext still appears as a singleline edittext

[image]

i would like the edittext take as much as possible of the window space

==============================UPDATE==================================

another thing is that when the keyboard is shown the action button doesnt add a new line it is just some sort of OK button.

i want a very simple alertdialog with multline edittext... why so difficult

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add LayoutParams for the Edittext

```
final EditText inputImports = new EditText(getContext());
inputImports.setMaxLines(500);
inputImports.setInputType(TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
inputImports.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

**Edit**

replace

```
   inputImports.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
```

with

```
   inputImports.getLayoutParams().height =  ((AlertDialog) dialog12).getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();
```